# What physical traits are derived from the Neanderthal DNA in human DNA?

Tags: human-biology, genomics, genomes, human-genome

Some researches had found that Human DNA has a bit of Neanderthal DNA. So they suggested there would have been crossing between *Homo sapiens* and Neanderthals.

Now the Neanderthal looked a bit different from *Homo sapiens*, so is there something in human that has some neanderthal looks?

And is it only found in European people or also in Asian or African people. Could it be be possible that a larger hairiness of European man is due to Neanderthal DNA?

Answer (score 1):

There was a very readable piece on this topic by [Chris Stringer in Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v485/n7396/full/485033a.html) in 2012. At that time his general conclusion was:

> It is not yet clear whether the archaic DNA many of us carry is tied to any visible traits.

Although he added:

> More controversially, some of the known differences in coding DNA
>   between Neanderthals and recent humans are associated with brain
>   development and function

quoting the [paper in Science (2010)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/328/5979/710.long) in which the Neanderthal sequence was published. There may be more recent information of which I am not aware.

As to your question about Neanderthal DNA in different populations, it is *not* present in people of African origin, but is present in those of Europeans and Asian origin.

Comment: Some more recent work has also linked Neanderthal-derived alleles with a plethora of phenotypes. See [Sankararaman et al. Nature 2014](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7492/full/nature12961.html), [Vernot and Akey. Science 2016](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/343/6174/1017.full), and [Simonti et al. Science 20160](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6274/737.full). Also a nice summary: [Our hidden Neandertal DNA may increase risk of allergies, depression](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/02/our-hidden-neandertal-dna-may-increase-risk-allergies-depression)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected there was more recent stuff. You should add it as your own  answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @David's answer, there has been some recent work looking at Neanderthal DNA in the context of Denisovan and modern human populations.

David Reich's group [[Sankararaman et al. Nature 2014](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7492/full/nature12961.html)] found Neanderthal-derived alleles in genes that affect skin and hair (specifically keratin filaments), as well as some that confer risk of disease. Another cool finding:

> ... there is an approximately fivefold reduction of Neanderthal ancestry
>   on the X chromosome, which is known from studies of diverse species to
>   be especially dense in male hybrid sterility genes. These
>   results suggest that part of the explanation for genomic regions of
>   reduced Neanderthal ancestry is Neanderthal alleles that caused
>   decreased fertility in males when moved to a modern human genetic
>   background.

A pair of papers from the groups of Joshua Akey [[Vernot and Akey. Science 2016](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/343/6174/1017.full)] and Tony Capra [[Simonti et al. Science 2016](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6274/737.full)] found associations between Neanderthal alleles and various phenotypes including depression, hypercoagulation, and tobacco use. These results are nicely summarized [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/02/our-hidden-neandertal-dna-may-increase-risk-allergies-depression).